# How to use `if let Ok()` syntax for a tuple which requires annotations

Tags: rust

I would like to know if it's possible to use `if let Ok()` syntax on `Result<Tuple(Struct, usize), DecodeError>` type returned from `bincode::decode_from_slice` function of `bincode` crate https://docs.rs/bincode/2.0.0-rc.3/bincode/fn.decode_from_slice.html which requires explicit type annotations

I tried the following syntax

```
struct A {
    a: i32,
    b: i32,
}

let mut recv_buff = [0u8; 1024];

if let Ok((a_obj, _): (A, usize)) = bincode::decode_from_slice(recv_buff, bincode::config::standard().with_big_endian()) {
        
}
```

Error

```
if let Ok((a_obj, _): (A, usize)) = bincode::decode_from_slice(recv_buff, bincode::config::standard()....
    |                                         ^ expected one of `)`, `,`, or `|`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't add annotatinos to `if let`, but you can just specify the generic type you want.

```rust
struct A {
    a: i32,
    b: i32,
}

let mut recv_buff = [0u8; 1024];

// We don't care about the config type so we use `_` as a placeholder for it's type
if let Ok((a_obj, _)) = bincode::decode_from_slice::<A, _>(
        recv_buff,
        bincode::config::standard().with_big_endian(),
) {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

While Rust doesn't allow type ascription inside the pattern, it's still *very* flexible about type annotations. The other answer shows how to specify type using turbofish on `decode_from_slice()`, but you can also:

- specify the generic types on the `Result::Ok` enum variant:

```
    if let Ok::<(A, usize), _>((a_obj, _)) =
        bincode::decode_from_slice(&recv_buff, bincode::config::standard().with_big_endian())
    {
        // ...
    }
```

- rebind the variables inside the block, and specify the types there:

```
    if let Ok((a_obj, b_obj)) =
        bincode::decode_from_slice(&recv_buff, bincode::config::standard().with_big_endian())
    {
        let (a_obj, _): (A, usize) = (a_obj, b_obj);
        // ...
    }
```

The latter form comes very useful when you need to specify the type of a `for` loop variable.